# Regex for text inside double quotes

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to match these strings:

`" ... "` Text inside double quotes

`' ... '` Text inside single quotes

`" ' "`   There can be apostrophes inside

`" \" "`  There can be escaped double quotes

But not these:

`' " '` Not double quotes inside single quotes

`" " "` Not double quotes inside double quotes

`'''`   Single quotes inside single quotes - Single quotes can only contain text inside

I have came up with the following regex:

```
['"](?(["])[^\"-"][\w])['"]
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Provide sample input data and your expected matches

Comment: What about apostrophes inside single-quotes strings?

Comment: Why no double quotes in single quotes? That is one of the primary usages of single quoting, so that you can use other types of quotes without escaping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually to match quotes with escapes as in C styled languages (and with single quoting as in JS) you could use:

```
"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'
```

Comment: It matches this and it shouldn't: '"'

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*?"|'(?:[^\\"']|\\.)*?'
```

I've followed what you've put but I wonder about it (Why no double quotes inside single quotes? I have not allowed a single quote inside single quotes though you've said nothing about that).

Either way, here is [an example](http://regex101.com/r/pW4uC7/1)

Comment: It doesn't work for the second case, ie. text inside single quotes

Comment: I changed the escaping as I had been careless with it but even before it worked fine with single quotes. see the example.

Comment: It seems to work but I don't understand why if the allowed token is \", then the regex is : "\\ So the other way round?

Comment: I assume you're talking about `[^"\\]`? I think you're misunderstanding the meaning of that (P.S. the example I linked to explains that well). the `[^]` construct means none of the characters that are inside that group, so `[^"\\]` means any character but `"` and `\` (since you need to escape backslashes). you then have that or (`|`) `\\"` 0 or more times which means you can have `\"` but not `"` inside the brackets.

Comment: So how does it know it has to enter in `[^"\\]` when \", but it has to enter in `\\` otherwise? I really can't understand.

Comment: Also it's not working fine for this case `"\he\"llo"`

Comment: You're right, I just fixed it so that it will work for that case now. I don't really understand your question, first go to the regex101 site and look at the explanation there. Then if you've got a specific question then let me know and I'll see if I can help you.

Comment: I have read it but it one side of the expression you negate \\ (^), and on the other side of the expression you don't, so I'm not sure how it works `?:[^\\"]|\\.`

Comment: ok, sure. so the thing we are looking at is `(?:[^\\"]|\\.)` the `(?:)` just means non-capturing group, so we can ignore that (it's grouping the things together and then we apply the 0 or more times operator to that grouping). The grouping consists of either of two parts. It will either match `[^\\"]` or any one character that is not a `"` or a `\ ` . Or it will match `\\.` which is a `\ ` followed by any character.

Comment: I think your format in the comment got broken somehow at the end

Comment: yes, those backslashes shouldn't have spaces after them but I think I was escaping the markdown, does it make sense now?

Comment: So the first part doesn't match `\`, but the second part matches `\` That's what baffles me. Thanks for your detailed explanation anyways